# Prioritizing the test results in python

Tags: unit-testing, python-2.7

I am looking for a way to prioritise my test results in python unit testing framework. I know that few tests are failing and i want to mark them as medium(unblocking for the result). I am doing api testing. I also would like to see the URI and the user credentials which was used for each test that was failing.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to resolve my first issue myself. Added @unittest.exectedFailure method from https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html doc. Now i want the failures come from details such as URI, user credentials used for failure cases, and it should be displayed for each case.